# Access the following childnodes in an XML file

Tags: vb.net

Good evening, my question is, how do I access the next node, the first row if you can read it, the second one not, my code is the following.

```
Private Sub llenarAlumno()
    Dim Xml As XmlDocument
    Dim NodeList As XmlNodeList
    Dim Node As XmlNode

    LlenarDS()
    Try
        Xml = New XmlDocument()
        Xml.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Empresas.xml") ' guarda tu xml en ruta de tu aplicacion. dentro de carpeta debug
        NodeList = Xml.SelectNodes("/Empresas/Empresa")
        For Each Node In NodeList
            Dim rw As DataRow = dsdetalle.Tables(0).NewRow
            rw("CedulaJuridica") = Node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText

            rw("RazonSocial") = Node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText



            dsdetalle.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rw)

        Next

        Me.dgvClientesFactura.DataSource = dsdetalle.Tables(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.GetType.ToString & vbNewLine & ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        Console.Read()
    End Try
End Sub
```

My xml file is like this

```
<Empresas>
<Empresa>
<CedulaJuridica>3101162637</CedulaJuridica>
<RazonSocial>kUNG FU PANDA MOVIES S A</RazonSocial>
<Direccion/>
<Provincia/>
<Canton/>
<Telefono/>
</Empresa>    
 </Empresas>
```

Comment: you call the Item(0) for 'RazonSocial' again. shouldn't it be Item(1)?

Comment: You should provide at least 1 complete XML entry for testing.

Comment: The way to figure this out is to add a watch to `Node.ChildNodes`.  You will be able to drill down the watch in the Watch Window  and better see how the data structured.